# How to find the mean of every element in a python dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, average

```
 comp_dict = {'ap': {'val': 0.3, 'count': 3}, 'sd': {'val': 0.02, 'count': 1}, 'ao': {'val': 0.01, 'count': 1}}

 avg_rate = {}
 for value in comp_dict.keys():
     avg_rate[value] = comp_dict[value]['val']/comp_dict[value]['count']
 print(avg_rate[value])
```

It seems like the output I got only generates the average I want for the last element and I am wondering how is it possible for me to get the mean for all three elements.

the output i got now is just `0.01`

My desired output would be something like `{ap:0.1,sd:0.02,ao:0.01}`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `print(avg_rate)`?

Comment: ... instead of `print(avg_rate[value])`?

Answer (score 1):

You just made a little mistake when you print out the avg_rate value.

you can do this:

```
avg_rate = {}
 for value in comp_dict.keys():
     avg_rate[value] = comp_dict[value]['val']/comp_dict[value]['count']
 print(avg_rate)
```

given `comp_dict = {'ap': {'val': 0.3, 'count': 3}, 'sd': {'val': 0.02, 'count': 1}, 'ao': {'val': 0.01, 'count': 1}}` ,

the output is:

`{'ap': 0.09999999999999999, 'sd': 0.02, 'ao': 0.01}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would work

```
avg_rate = {k:comp_dict[k]['val']/comp_dict[k]['count'] for k in comp_dict for k2 in comp_dict[k]}
```

Comment: this works but i tried what shaik said and it was more straightforward. But still, appreciate the help!